# Inverted harmonic oscillator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations, operator-theory

I am looking for the spectrum of th inverted oscillator $H=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-x^2$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $H$ has a continuous spectrum. What do you like to know?

Comment: So what is its continuous spectrum?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0703234

Comment: Thank you for the article, i am looking for a mathematical study on the spectrum, if you have it please give it to me

Comment: what is his  spectrum continuous?

Comment: @FadilKikawi Why don't you follow up on the references given in the article that was cited before you ask followup questions here?

Comment: Because I want a mathematical study

Answer (score 5):

The question is only precise once a self-adjointness domain is spelled out for $H$. One way to do this is to regard $H$ as infinitesimal generator of the metaplectic representation  in $L^2(\mathbf R)$ of a one-parameter subgroup of (the double cover of) $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf R)$. Then its spectrum is the whole real line, with multiplicity 2 and parabolic cylinder functions as (generalized, non-square integrable) eigenfunctions. This is described with increasing detail in Kalnins-Miller ([1974](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=372382), p. 1733); Wolf ([1976](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=411447), p. 604); Wolf ([1979](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=529766), pp. 321-328, 347, 392).

Comment: I would be very grateful if you can give me the links of your proposals documentations

Comment: @FadilKikawi https://www.ima.umn.edu/~miller/bibli.html http://www.fis.unam.mx/~bwolf/resources.html

Comment: Please specify the links of the documentations about the  "is to regard $H$ as infinitesimal generator of the metaplectic representation in  $L^2(R)$. Thank you very much

Comment: @FadilKikawi That was just my way of saying it quickly -- those papers use other methods of specifying the domain; please refer to them. The point is that you must specify it *somehow*, otherwise your problem is totally ill-defined. (Who's to say you're not considering "$-d^2/dx^2 -x^2$" on polynomials, or polynomials times $\exp(ix^2/2)$, or smooth functions on $(3,7)$, or whatever? That can change the answer completely.)

Answer (score 5):

The operator (on $L^2(\mathbb R)$) has purely absolutely continuous spectrum $\sigma_{ac}=(-\infty,\infty)$ of multiplicity $2$. I don't think that's very easy to see, and it definitely depends on the specifics of the situation; for example, if we make the potential more negative still, then the operator will be in the limit circle case and the spectrum becomes discrete.

I'll give a sketch, but this will not be very detailed.
I suggest to analyze the ODE $-y''-x^2y = Ey$ asymptotically. This is a standard procedure, but it will require some calculations. Let $Y=(y,y')^t$, so $Y'=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ E+x^2 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)Y$, and write $Y= TZ$, where
$$
T=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ i\omega & - i\omega \end{pmatrix} , \quad\quad \omega = \sqrt{E+x^2},
$$
is chosen such that it diagonalizes the coefficient matrix. We find that
$$
Z' = \begin{pmatrix} i\omega + g & -g \\ -g & -i\omega +g \end{pmatrix} Z, \quad\quad g(x) = \frac{\omega'}{2\omega} = \frac{x}{2(E+x^2)} .
$$
Next, write $Z=(1+Q)U$, so $U$ solves
$$
Q'U + (1+Q)U' = i\omega \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}(1+Q)U + g\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} (1+Q)U .
$$
We now choose $Q$ as a solution of
$$
Q' = i\omega (DQ-QD) - g \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} Q, \quad\quad D= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} .
$$
This can be solved explicitly, and we then see that we can in fact choose a solution $Q(x) = O(\omega^{-1/2})= O(x^{-1/2})$. This simplifies matters considerably if we are willing to ignore $L^1$ terms: $U$ solves
$$
U'= \left[ \begin{pmatrix} i\omega + g & 0 \\ 0 &-i\omega + g \end{pmatrix} + R \right] U, \quad\quad R\in L^1 .
$$
Now Levinson's theorem on the asymptotic integration of such systems gives us basis solutions of the form $U=e_j \omega^{1/2} e^{\pm i\alpha(x)}(1+o(1))$. We go back to $y$ and obtain two solutions of the form $y\simeq \omega(x)^{1/2}e^{\pm i\alpha(x)}$. Since all solutions are asymptotically of the same size, my claims about the spectrum follow (by the subordinacy theory).