# Weyl sequence for $H_a=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+a^2x^2$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory

We consider the following Operator: $H_a=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+a^2x^2$ were $a\in R^{*}$.

Let be $b\in R$. I want to construct a sequence $w_n$ (Which depends on $b$)such that:

1-$||w_n||_2=1$.

2-$w_n$ Converges weakly to $0$.

3- $ ||(H_a   -  b)w_n||_2\to  0$

Thank you in adavence

Comment: Typo: in order that $H_a\phi=ia\phi$ I guess you want $\phi(x)=e^{iax^2/2}$?

Comment: Typo: I believe "$\forall b\in\mathbf R$" should be moved to immediately before "I want".

Comment: The existence of such a sequence (for a fixed $b$, your formulation in (3) is misleading) is equivalent to $b$ being in the essential spectrum (Weyl's criterion). In the answers to your previous question, you already got more detailed information on the spectrum of $H_a$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you have already been given references to the relevant literature. Go study them.

Comment: @Michael Renardy.  I did not find my question about the references cited

Answer (score 4):

There is no such ('Weyl') sequence, even satisfying just 1 and 3 (*before* your edit, i.e. with $b=ia$). In fact, replies to your [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258077/inverted-harmonic-oscillator) (assumed accepted...) show that $H_a$ has spectrum $\mathbf R$. So $ia$ is not in it, i.e. $H_a-ia$ has bounded inverse. So 3 implies
$$
\|w_n\|=\|(H_a-ia)^{-1}(H_a-ia)w_n\|\leqslant\|(H_a-ia)^{-1}\|\|(H_a-ia)w_n\|\to0
$$
which contradicts 1.

**Later.** *After* your edit: existence of such $w_n$ is precisely [Weyl's criterion](https://books.google.com/books?id=GhAGCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA70) that $b\in\sigma_{\mathrm{ess}}(H_a)=\mathbf R$. So you might just use its known proof. (Sketch: for $b$ in the spectrum, $H_a-b$ has *unbounded* inverse. So there are $v_n$ such that $\|v_n\|=1$ and $\|(H_a-b)^{-1}v_n\|\to\infty$. Then one checks that
$$
w_n:=\frac{(H_a-b)^{-1}v_n}{\|(H_a-b)^{-1}v_n\|}
$$
does the trick.)

Comment: Yes, $\phi(x)=e^{i\frac{a}{2}x^2}$,It can also be seen by $||(H_a   -  ia)w_n||^2=||(H_a w_n||^2+||ia w_n||^2=$ so, if $||(H_a   -  ia)w_n||^2\to 0$ we get  $ ||ia w_n||\to 0$ which contradicts 1.

Comment: I corrected the statement

Comment: Francois Ziegler@ i want to construct such sequence without use $\sigma_{ess}(H_a)=R$. In fact I want to show $\sigma_{ess}(H_a)=R$